# When I remove text using str_replace, () is obtained instead of text

Tags: php

I get the name of the items from the CS: GO game by API. Item name is as follows: `1st Lieutenant Farlow | SWAT (Superior)`, when parsing I try to remove this: `(Superior)`, together with parentheses, but it turns out to remove only Superior, but the parentheses remain and i received `1st Lieutenant Farlow | SWAT ()`. It show only if i make `var_dump`, but if i start parsing, it's not updated :(

My function with update all information what i need:

```
public function update_information()
{
    $prices = json_decode(file_get_contents('http://csgobackpack.net/api/GetItemsList/v2/?prettyprint=true'), true);

    if (!$prices['success']) {
        dd('Error');
    }

    $newPrices = [];
    $newColor = [];

    foreach ($prices['items_list'] as $price) {
        $newPrices[$price['name']] = $price['rarity'];
        $newColor[$price['name']] = $price['rarity_color'];
    }

    $totalUpdated = 0;

    foreach (AllItem::query()->get() as $itemDB) {
        $fullName = $itemDB->market_hash_name;
        $newName = str_replace($itemDB->exterior, '', $fullName);

        if (!isset($newPrices[$fullName])) {
            continue;
        }

        if (!isset($newColor[$fullName])) {
            continue;
        }

        $itemDB->update(['market_hash_name' => $newName]);
        $itemDB->update(['exterior' => $newPrices[$fullName]]);
        $itemDB->update(['rarity' => $newPrices[$fullName]]);
        $itemDB->update(['rarity_color' => $newColor[$fullName]]);
        $totalUpdated++;
    }

    dd('done. Updated images: ' . $totalUpdated);
}
```

Where is my mistake? Maybe `$newName` vatiable is wrong? How i can remove brackets?

Comment: `var_dump` say me result `string(28) "AK-47 | Aquamarine Revenge (Battle-Scarred)"` it's next item, and i need to remove `(Battle-Scarred)` from this result

Comment: Wouldn't str_replace('(' . $itemDB->exterior . ')', '', $fullName); do the trick you want?

Answer (score 1):

Just add the parentheses to the value you're trying to remove. I'd trim it afterwards, as well.

```
$newName = trim(str_replace('('.$itemDB->exterior.')', '', $fullName));
```

Comment: hm... it's not update my all existing database values, but `->update` method is used..